# why doesn't list_companies() return the companies I created in Google cloud Talent Solution?

Tags: python, google-cloud-talent-solution

I have:

```
from google.cloud import talent_v4beta1
CLIENT = talent_v4beta1.CompanyServiceClient()
PROJECT_ID = '...'
PROJECT_PATH = 'projects/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID)

company = {
    'display_name' : ...,
    'external_id' : ...
}

# this call successful creates a new company
CLIENT.create_company(PROJECT_PATH, company)

# this call doesn't return any companies
CLIENT.list_companies(PROJECT_PATH)
```

When I use the Google API Explorer to try out `list_companies` it successfully returns the companies I have created.

If I try to again call `CLIENT.create_company(PROJECT_PATH, company)`  with the same `company` dict from my project it successfully throws `exceptions.AlreadyExists`

Where's the misstep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looping over the contents and checking?

```
for ele in CLIENT.list_companies(PROJECT_PATH):
    print(ele)
```

Comment: I've been doing response = CLIENT.list_companies(... and printing response.num_results which prints as 0. Looping reveals the data! A big thank you! With_results displaying 0 I was totally misdirected.